# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server - WIndows 11

Tags: oracle, linked-server, ssms-19

I am unable to connect to an oracle linked server from SSMS 19.

Its working from another machine that similar configuration with SSMS18 but downgrading to SSMS is not working on the new machine. Can someone please point out to the missing drivers(if any)

Here is the error I am getting -
[image]

I have a UNC path for TNSNames.ora file in my environment variable "TNS_ADMIN"